# How to refer to Obj file when storing tab file name in a String variable?

Tags: mapinfo

I need to loop through tab files and use select, am doing the following:

```
 Dim file_name as string
 Dim file_name_obj as string

 file_name = area1
 file_name_obj = area1.Obj
```

Am getting an "Datatype mismatch in expression" message in MapInfo, is it incorrect to have the above assignment? and what is the alternative method to refer to object files while file name is stored in a string variable?

Comment: Where are you instantiating the 'area1' variable? As what datatype?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the alias variable type

```
Dim file_name as string
Dim file_name_obj as alias

file_name = area1
file_name_obj = file_name + ".obj"
note file_name_obj
```

Assuming area1 is the name of an open table containing a polygon, if you run this code you will get a popup stating the geometry type (e.g. region) which confirms there is now an object stored in the file_name_obj variable.

Comment: You might want to add quotes around your table name: file_name = "area1"